# Why my active window minimizes when I switch to next work space?

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have horrible problem which is on my nerve :( It started to happen when I changed its shortcut from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right arrows</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1/3</kbd> since it had conflict with my Android Studio.

This new assignment (shortcut) works fine and I'm able to switch between left and right workspaces. However, by switch to each workspace, its active window sticks to right corner of screen.

- For sake of visual explanation, let say this is screenshot of my screen.

[image]

- Now, I switch to right workspace by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>
- Then again I switch back to left workspace by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- My screen looks like this

[image]

Same thing happens for active window on second workspace. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the numpad keys, which are different than the number keys above the keyboard (and to which the shortcut you tried to set actually likely refers), then what happens is this:

bottom right number on the numpad is 3, therefore ctrl+alt+3 will focus that window to the bottom right of the page.

following that pattern, 1 is bottom left corner, 7 is top left corner, 9 is top right, 8 is top half, 2 is bottom half, 5 is full screen, etc.

These shortcuts are viewable in the 'grid' section of the compiz settings manager.

Comment: thanks. yup, I found the issue and changed my shortcut. Thanks for answering the question.